# jQuery library from Google CDN 800 ms to load

Tags: jquery, cdn

I don't know whether to use the Google CDN or host local the jQuery library.

After generating a report from pingdomtools (http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/MQVMRzfaf/tandregulering.info) i notice it takes quite a long time to fetch it.

See screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/1C073q0F3s1G

What can I do to bring down the load time of the jQuery library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using the non-https version since the rest of your site isn't https.

Comment: It should load faster from the CDN because it can be done in parallel to the other assets due to it being on a different domain, and the fact that with the cdn, it may be cached by the user already. Why do you use a cache-buster querystring on the cdn url?

Answer (score 1):

In general it should load faster from the Google CDN than from your own server since a lot of sites use the CDN and a lot of people have it cached in their browser.

BTW: Why don't you test it from your local machine, using the developer tools that ship with Safari, Chrome, Firefox or IE?

edit: Plus one for  Kevin B's comment: If you don't specify the protocol (just leave https out, it chooses http automatically)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```